# Resolve promises sequentially after event

Tags: javascript, promise

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08hg45bc/1/). I want to allow my app to push items as needed into a queue to be resolved on user event (e.g., a click).

I'm doing this now through `obtainItem()`, where I create `toDo` as a promise and push into `obtainedItemsQueue`, but the events are all being resolved at once, rather than waiting to be resolved via the button click.

In this example, what should happen is:

- user should be notified that `map` was obtained, then they click "Okay"
- After they click "Okay", they will be notified that `bag` was obtained
- Finally, after clicking "Okay", they will be notified `shirt` was obtained

How can I push multiple promises into a queue, and resolve on an event such as click?

```
let obtainedItemsQueue = [];

function obtainItem(itemStr) {
    let toDo = new Promise(resolve => {
        $('.content').append(`<span class="text">${itemStr}</span>`);
        $('.content').append('<button>Okay</button>');
        $('button').on('click', function() {
          $('.content').empty();
          resolve(`${itemStr} is resolved.`);
        });
  });

  obtainedItemsQueue.push(toDo);
}

obtainItem('map');
obtainItem('bag');
obtainItem('shirt');

function resolveItems() {
  let chain = Promise.resolve();
  obtainedItemsQueue.forEach((item) => {
        chain = chain.then(() => item);
  });


  return chain;
}

resolveItems();
```

Comment: You don't want to call the next `obtainItem()` until the first one finishes.

Comment: @SLaks the idea is that you'd be obtaining `n` items at a given time (let's say, you complete some task and get 3 things at once), so I want to load them up to sequentially notify the user. So the app will say "Hey, the user got this, this and this. Whenever they're ready (i.e. they click 'Okay'), we'll tell them about the next thing you got." How would I structure that?

Comment: `let toDo = () => new Promise(resolve => {` ... and `chain = chain.then(item);` perhaps?

Comment: @JaromandaX ah right. Return the Promise from a function and call that function. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also write `resolveItems` function like `return obtainedItemsQueue.reduce((chain, item) => chain.then(item), Promise.resolve());` - but that's because I'm a "try to do it in one line" nerd :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08hg45bc/2/)

change `toDo` to be a function that returns the promise

```
let obtainedItemsQueue = [];

function obtainItem(itemStr) {
    let toDo = () => new Promise(resolve => {
        $('.content').append(`<span class="text">${itemStr}</span>`);
        $('.content').append('<button>Okay</button>');
        $('button').on('click', function() {
            $('.content').empty();
            resolve(`${itemStr} is resolved.`);
        });
    });

    obtainedItemsQueue.push(toDo);
}

obtainItem('map');
obtainItem('bag');
obtainItem('shirt');
```

and change the chain.then to execute the `item` which is now a function

```
function resolveItems() {
    let chain = Promise.resolve();
    obtainedItemsQueue.forEach((item) => {
        chain = chain.then(item);
    });
    return chain;
}

resolveItems();
```

Comment: Somebody, somewhere needs to remove those `.on('click')` handlers after they're used.  Maybe use `.once()` instead.  And, `obtainItem()` can never be called while one is already in progress or things will not work properly (which is why promises aren't a good impedance match for recurring events).

Comment: @jfriend00 - `$('.content').empty();`? (not that I would write this code this way, the answer was a "minimal change" sort of thing

Comment: Yuck, that is smelly code.  I see your point.  They are apparently removing the button itself that got pushed so no need to remove the event handlers on it.  Note to the OP: With a little more context, there are certainly better ways to solve this particular problem.